# some vertically stacked DIVs become invisible

Tags: html, css

I'm building a sort of map grid in HTML/CSS with the following structure:

```css
#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2vw;
    bottom: 2vw;
    left: 2vw;
    right: 2vw;
    overflow: visible;
    background : blue;
}

.map-row {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.map-row-split {
    
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
    <div class="map-row" style="height:9.8%;"></div>
    <div class="map-row-split" style="height:0.2%"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, it's a map with 10 rows and, as you see, the total height amount to 100% of the parent.

The only styling is that both `map-row` and `map-row-split` have `width=100%`, but the outcome hides one of the split divs for some reason:

[image]

Which split divs disappear (and how many) depends on the size of the parent, for example this is a smaller parent size:

[image]

Comment: Can you create SO Snippet with your code?

Comment: @Justinas Sorry but how do I do that? I don't see the option anywhere.

Comment: It's icon in editor dashboard next to image and has `<>` on it

Comment: As you see the wrapper div is absolutely positioned and resizes with the screen size.

Comment: Try setting `min-height: 1px` to your `.map-row-split`. Your example has `0.38331px` height and when browser renders this element, than it may lead to `0px` height

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. Although it does create a problem with overflow but I'll handle that with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer from comment*

Set `min-height: 1px` to `.map-row-split`, as setting height to fraction of pixel may lead to some visual inconsistency/issues from browser side.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height of `html` and `body` to `100%`.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything really? There's already a wrapper div (see snippet).

Comment: Well, that was before you added them inside a div. However, I'd still give you an explanation. You had used % to set the height, which actually depends on the parent's height. And the height of the html, and body as large as the content inside it.

So you need to set the height of html and body to be 100% of the document. You may or may not have come across this situation when you'd have set a background image, and even though you set no-repeat, the image still appears messed up, somewhere at the bottom of the document.